# Multi Thread VB.Net with OLEDB database

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, oledb

Before I start, please excuse me if I don't initially explain this very well! There's way too much code to post, so I'll have to paraphrase what I'm doing.

I am developing a program which uses an OLEDB database connection.

I'm splitting the program into classes to do different parts of the processing. There will be one method which sets different methods/classes off in parallel threads to do different things. As each thread finishes it will write to the database. The database writing will be completed in the class which contains the method that sets the threads off.

So, ClassA_MethodA sets the threads going via ClassA_MethodB and ClassA_MethodB will write to the database.

Depending on various parameters, ClassA_MethodB will get it's data from either ClassC_MethodA, ClassD_MethodA or ClassP_MethodA

ClassC_MethodA and ClassD_MethodA need to read from the OLEDB database. Because of the number of threads that may be running, I can't have one connection per thread so all need to use a shared connection which is passed to each Class as a parameter. This all seems to work OK so far when they're all reading.

Question is about transactions and/or locks.

Scenarios are that each thread (ClassA_MethodB) will either write to a unique table (no parallel writes) *OR* will write to the same table, but with unique values (e.g. each will have a unique index value) so there's no chance of two threads trying to write the same data, or different values for the same index.

If I wrap the writing process of each thread in a transaction, will this cause an issue if ClassP_MethodA for example tries to read the lastest value in that same table whilst ClassA_MethodB is writing?

If I use:

```
 Monitor.Enter(tableWriteLock)
 'write my data
 Monitor.Exit(tableWriteLock)
```

can I pass the status of the lock to ClassP_MethodA (for example) so it doesn't try to read whilst the write is taking place?

Probably sounds like a load of twaddle to the experts out there, but I sort of know what I'm trying to achieve - just can't express it very well!

Comment: You should always post code. If the code is too long then make a [mcve].

Comment: Now, it is very unlikely that threading will save you any time. You're writing to a database so the write time will be orders of magnitude slower than an improvement that threading gives you. You will also need to fire up your database connection for each new thread as connections are not thread-safe (even with locking). What does work well is creating a single background thread to do all of your db activity.

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity. Each thread can't have a connection as there could be in excess of 64 running and the database can only cope with 64 simultaneous connections. Each thread completes a calculation process, which will vary in complexity between threads, then writes that to the database on completion.

Comment: Then you can't use threads like you're suggesting. You **must** have a connection **per thread**. But it is likely to be much fast to have only **one single background thread** than to have multiple.

Comment: Perhaps you could have your threads perform their calculations and then put their results into a queue which is processed by another thread that only does database operations.

Comment: Thanks Chris - that makes sense. Is it acceptable for each thread to _read_ from the database but then instigate a queue process for writing, as each needs to look up base data before it can perform its functions?